# How to compare two ArrayList<List<String>>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to compare these two `ArrayList`:

```
public static ArrayList<List<String>> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
public static ArrayList<List<String>> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

If they have the same elements it will return true, otherwise false.

Comment: Try to do it yourself.If you are getting any error in that,post it here.

Comment: I've tried it. Its just that I am looking for good algorithm.

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using Apache commons [CollectionUtils.retainAll](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) method : Returns a collection containing all the elements in collection1 that are also in collection2.

```
ArrayList commonList = CollectionUtils.retainAll(arrayList1, arrayList2);
```

If the size of commonList is equal to　`arrayList1`　and `arrayList2` you can say both the list are same.

Comment: What if they have the same size, but different element's values?

Comment: Try reading the API definition. It says it will return the list of elements that are same in both arrayList1 and arrayList2.

Comment: *"What if they have the same size, but different element's values?"* - Why would that be a problem?  Hint: **READ** the linked javadocs!

Comment: Every question here can be answered by "read the java docs", why haven't we thought of that? Here's your +1.

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried

```
  arrayList1 .equals ( arrayList2 )
```

which is true, if they contain the same elements in the same order

or

```
new HashSet(arrayList1) .equals (new HashSet(arrayList2))
```

if the order does not matter

See http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it yourself without any dependencies.

```
public class ListComparator<T> {

    public Boolean compare(List<List<T>> a, List<List<T>> b) {
        if (a.size() != b.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (a.get(i).size() != b.get(i).size()) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < a.get(i).size(); k++) {
                if(!a.get(i).get(k).equals(b.get(i).get(k))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

And using

```
  ListComparator<String> compare = new ListComparator<String>();
  System.out.println(compare.compare(arrayList1, arrayList2));
```

I don't use foreach statement because i had read this post http://habrahabr.ru/post/164177/ 
(on russian), but you can translate it to english.

Comment: Calling `a.get(i).size()` will result in a NullPointerException if the element at position `i` is null.

Comment: How we can get `a.get(i).size()` as `a.get(i)` will retrun a string and string doesn't have `size()` method?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is used. This checks whether two list have same element or not. 
-->> list1.equals(list2)