# Java: How do I compare a List<String> with List<List<String>>?

Tags: java, oop, collections

There is an ArrayList1 and a List2 containing several arraylists in it.

I want to compare the contents in arraylist1 with all the arraylists(in List2) and throw out the records from List2 which are not equal to arraylist1.

There are couple of questions similar to this one, but I could't understand it clearly. Please help.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and describe what doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to implement, iterate:

```
List<String> yourSingleList = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<String> list : yourListOfLists) {
    //remove entries
    list.retainAll(yourSingleList);
    //or remove matching entities
    list.removeAll(yourSingleList);
}
```

Or use an iterator to compare entirely:

```
List<String> yourSingleList = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<List<String>> lists = yourListOfLists.iterator();
while (lists.hasNext()) {
    if (!lists.next().equals(yourSingleList) {
        lists.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Two lists are equals only if these have the same elements in the same order.But the OP wants to delete the records which are present in another list

Comment: So then simply utilize the iterative method, I covered both because I wasn't 100% certain of the question being asked.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like that:

```
    List<List<String>> listlist = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    // some example input here
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");

    listlist.add(list);

    for (List<String> l : listlist) {
        for(String s : l) {
            if (list.contains(s)) {
                System.out.println(s + " is at position " + list.indexOf(s));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [How to compare two ArrayList<List<String>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545303/how-to-compare-two-arraylistliststring)
Think about it like a two dimensional array and compare each element of list A to each element in list B.get(1), list B.get(2), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a homework question so here is the logic

```
input: List of Arrays, Array
output: List

List Compiar getList(L, A):
|   newL <- new List
|   for each Array a in L do
|   |   for int i <- 0 to A.size()
|   |   |   Array n = new Array
|   |   |   for int j <- 0 to a.size()
|   |   |   |   if  compairitor(A.get(i), a.get(j)) = 0 // compairitor is used to compair values
|   |   |   |   |    n.add(a.get(j)
|   |   |   |   end-if
|   |   |   end-for
|   |   |   newL.add(n)
|   |   end-for
|   end-for-each    
|     return newL
end
```

Use this method to replase the old list ex List old = getList(L, Comparison  array)