# Java - best way to compare two List<List<String>>?

Tags: java, list, compare

What's the best way to compare the String elements of two `List<List<String>>`...

At the end, I want to know if they contain the same elements (true) or not (false)

This two lists I want to compare:

```
ObservableList<List<String>> fnlData = FXCollections.observableList(new LinkedList<>());;

List<List<String>> fnlDataTMP = new LinkedList<>();
```

I searched for already answered questions in the forum, but nothing helped me ..

Comment: Have you checked this?

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545303/how-to-compare-two-arraylistliststring

Take a look at it.

Comment: Have you already tried `fnlData.equals(fnlDataTMP)`?

Comment: @Lathy  I cant use CollectionUtils ...

Comment: @Tom yes and it didnt work

Comment: combine `List<List<String>>` into one List<String> and do the normal list comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Try `fnlData.equals(fnlDataTMP)` if both list are in order

or if order does not matter, try creating hash set and then compare using equals

```
new HashSet(fnlData).equals(new HashSet(fnlDataTMP))
```

Comment: @tobias_k Different `List` types and if they don't override `equals`, then there isn't a problem with that.

Comment: @Tom I thought they would also check whether the class is equal, but apparently they don't. Just checked with `ArrayList` vs. `LinkedList` and they compared as equal (with content being equal). Thanks for the pointer. Still, it seems like OP has tried this and it did not work...

Comment: @tobias_k `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` don't override the `equals` method, so the version of `AbstractList` is used, which only checks if both are of type `List`.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need a double iteration

```
boolean checkEqual(List<List<String>> l1,List<List<String>> l2){
  if(l1.size() != l2.size()){
    return false;
  }
  if(l1.hashCode() != l2.hashCode()){
    return false;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<l1.size(); i++) {
    List<String> curr = l1.get(i);
    List<String> comp = l2.get(i);
    if(curr.size() != comp.size()){
      return false;
    }
    if(curr.hashCode() != comp.hashCode()){
      return false;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<curr.size(); j++) {
      if(!curr.get(j).equals(comp.get(j))){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

You can improve the solution checking first difference of hashCode

```
if(l1.hashCode() != l2.hashCode()){
  return false;
}
```

if hashCode are equal, then check eventually deep difference

Comment: the outer list's size could be over 100k, so it would take a lot of time to do that

Comment: @InfernoVol If you dont know anything about the lists, then you have to iterate over them. Maybe something is special in your case. To provide a faster search, we need to see your scenario.

Comment: The list could contain something like this: http://i.imgur.com/jfgcixg.png
The rows are the outer_list and the columns are the inner_list.
This file for example has ~90 000 rows.
And I could be, that in tempList just one String is different....

Comment: a more quick way is check hashCode before using iteration. If hashCode are not equal, then you can assure your lists are different

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way that let's you achieve that out of the box.

You can do something like the [functional java List.join](https://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/List.html#join(fj.data.List)) method to quickly generate 2 Lists and compare these:

```
List<String> joinedFnlData = jf.data.List.join(fnlData);
List<String> joinedFnlDataTMP = jf.data.List.join(fnlDataTMP);

CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(joinedFnlData, joinedFnlDataTMP);
```

Things to note:

- This is probably not the cheapest operation - so it should not be invoked too often in a time critical scenario (e.g. UI thread)
- It does not do a "real" equals - for that you would have to do a nested loop like in the above answer. This checks that both joined lists have the same elements with the same cardinality: e.g. if fnlData has 2 lists with "1" and "2" as the only elements and fnlDataTMP has 1 list with "1", "2" as the elements, this would mark both as equal. Depending on your scenario this might be irrelevant - if this is relevant I don't see a way around nested loops.

Comment: Somehow I cant use/import jf and CollectionUtils

Comment: CollectionUtils is from the apache-commons-collections library. The functional java jar file can be downloaded here: https://code.google.com/p/functionaljava/

Answer (score 1):

If by same elements you mean that the two lists are exacly the same but in a different order, then i suggest you sort the to lists and then compare them.

```
boolean isEqual(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        if (list1.size() != list2.size()) return false;
        Collections.sort(list1);
        Collections.sort(list2);
        int i = 0;
        for (String element : list1) {
            if (!element.equals(list2.get(i))) return false;
            i++;
         }
        return true;
    }
```

I didn't test it yet!

Comment: they are not exacly the same, it could be that one list has just one different string

Comment: @InfernoVol You said, that you want to know if both contain the same elements .. if already know, that they don't, then why do you check that?

Answer (score 1):

For a Collections (Lists) to be equal, both need to be a proper subset of each other. Thus `list1.containsAll(list2)` and `list2.containsAll(list1)`. 
For a List within a List, you will have to loop, but that's essentially what any built-in library has to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that doesn't need to have two inner loops by using [Collections.sort(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), which sorts a List in place, and [List.containsAll(java.util.Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which compares two Lists for their elements.

Sample Code:

```
    //Creating two lists for comparison and their inner lists
    List<List<String>> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    List<List<String>> list2 = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<String> l11 = new LinkedList<>();
    l11.add("a");
    l11.add("b");
    l11.add("c");

    LinkedList<String> l12 = new LinkedList<>();
    l12.add("d");
    l12.add("e");
    l12.add("f");

    LinkedList<String> l21 = new LinkedList<>();
    l21.add("b");
    l21.add("c");
    l21.add(new String("a"));

    LinkedList<String> l22 = new LinkedList<>();
    l22.add("d");
    l22.add("e");
    l22.add("f");

    list1.add(l11);
    list1.add(l12);
    list2.add(l22);
    list2.add(l21);

    for (List<String> list : list1){
        Collections.sort(list);
    }

    for (List<String> list : list2){
        Collections.sort(list);
    }

    System.out.println(list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1)); //prints true
```

If you don't want to change the order of the elements in the inner Lists you can create copies of the outer Lists and perform the operations on them.

**Note:** This only works for sortable collections.

Answer (score 0):

Store one of the list in a HashMap and then iterate through the other list and check if the Map already contains that KEY. Ofcourse you have to ensure that KEY types match.